# ¬(A∨¬A)⊢¬B in paracomplete systems

Tags: paradoxes, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I am considering a paracomplete logic where the principle ¬(A∨¬A)⊢¬B holds. What does it take for the principle to be explosive, such that we can infer any ¬B?

If we have some statement that is neither true nor false in this logic, can we infer any negated proposition? That is, is a truth value gap equivalent to ¬(A∨¬A)?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it important here that it's $\vdash \lnot B$ rather than $\vdash B$ ?

Comment: I understand that B is arbitrary so classically it wouldn't be, but I'm thinking in this case it is important because negation isn't classical. I've read that minimal logic for example validates A∧¬A⊢¬B but not A∧¬A⊢B. This is also a question I'm unsure about though.

Comment: Minimal logic rejects both LEM and the principle of explosion thus it is an intuitionistic and paraconsistent logic. Being intuitionistic means rejecting double negation which is the reason why it validates A∧¬A⊢¬B from applying negation introduction but not A∧¬A⊢B, since the latter is essentially proof by contradiction which invokes double negation unavoidbly. In minimal logic assuming any contradiction, then every proposition can be negated, but you cannot prove arbitrary proposition...

Comment: @mohottnad am I right in thinking that intuitionistically ¬B means B is not true but not ¬B is true, and hence those two forms of explosion are not equivalent?

Comment: In paraconsistent logic the form of explosion is weaker than classic/intuitionistic, and you're right in intuitionistic logic ¬B can be interpreted as B is false (also can be interpreted in various other ways such as B is unprovable), and since it rejects double negation ¬¬B doesn't mean B.

Comment: So is it correct that having ¬(A∨¬A)⊢¬B in a logic having statements that are not true, and whose negations are not true, leads to a form of explosion?

Comment: ¬(A∨¬A) may be a lot different than A∧¬A depending on your logic permitting double negation or not. In intuitionistic logics ¬(A∨¬A)⊢¬A∧¬¬A but ¬¬A⊢A doesn't hold, so you cannot say ¬(A∨¬A)⊢¬B in minimal logic. If your paraconsistent logic can have both a statement and its negation not true, then apparently it doesn't necessarily lead to complete explosion (a truth gap with neither true nor false, like some sentences recorded in ancient Suttas which doesn't mean you can claim arbitrary sentence). In negative theology, oneness is neither this nor not-this, but it may not be everything either...

Comment: @mohottnad You say that this paraconsistent logic doesn't lead to explosion, but if ¬(A∨¬A)⊢¬B holds in this logic, is that not explosion? Or negative explosion? This is the purpose of my question in the OP. I'm still not sure of the answer.

Comment: If ¬(A∨¬A)⊢¬B holds for arbitrary B in your proprietary logic, this is a form of weaker (controlled) explosion compared with classical PoE. Recall ¬(A∨¬A) is actually valid in all intuitionistic logics thus the left-hand of the turnstile is not a contradiction at all in such logics. So your paraconsistent logic must accept LEM (reject intuitionistic logic) and list ¬(A∨¬A)⊢¬B as your logical axiom (hard to see it can be derived from simpler logical axioms from above discussed proprietary logic). Most paraconsistent set theories turned out to be too weak mathematically due to weaker explosion.

Comment: Why must it accept LEM? To avoid explosion? I want precisely to reject LEM and assert ¬(A∨¬A)⊢¬B, and I'm not trying to avoid the explosion. I just want to understand what the explosion entails - what the difference is between normal explosion and this weaker explosion.

Comment: Recall (A∨¬A) is just LEM, so ¬(A∨¬A) can be accepted in intuitionism. And to get an explosion usually you need a contradiction in the antecedent. On the other hand A∧¬A is a true contradiction in most logics including intuitionism since it violates LNC, which is a different law of thoughts than LEM. As for the weaker form of explosion above, it only can explode to assert the negation of all true given sentences in your theory, but it cannot assert an arbitrary one permitted by your language out of the blue, while normal explosion can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131598/discussion-between-mohottnad-and-mazotu).